# How do I deploy hyperledger fabric to multiple instances? ie an instance for each organisation and the orderer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a fairly decent understanding of the network as a whole and I have successfully deployed test networks and apps onto a single instance.

Although trying to get fabric working over multiple instances is proving to be time consuming to work out.

I am deploying on google cloud, onto ubuntu 16.04. If anyone can help guide me through the process that would be great as most of the other answers to this question are vague or just point to scripts that haven't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment script.
For an example.

It deploys fabric to VMs / physical machines assuming you have passwordless ssh access via preconfigured ssh keys.

Currently it deploys a solo orderer but soon there will be a kafka orderer deployment too.

Comment: Does it deploy organisations onto their own instances?

Comment: Can you run through how to use the script?

Comment: It can currently only deploy a single organization. Maybe I'll add more organizations in the future.

To use the script just invoke ./deploy.sh   after you configure the config.sh